# How to get text from DropDownList in .net-MVC?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, html-select

Alright so i was using a text box like this :

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(u=>u.Time)
```

now i wanna replace the text box with a drop down list, i did this :

```
@Html.DropDownList("FromDD",new SelectList (new[] {"first","second","third"}))
```

how can i get the **text** from the dropDownList and save it in the model (Model.Time) ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given your example, the value you are looking for will be posted as a string called **FromDD**. The string you use as first parameter will be the name of the property the data binder is going to bind your value to.
If you want you can use the strongly typed overload

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(p => p.Time, new SelectList (new[] {"first","second","third"}))
```

this will post back the data as a string named **Time**, exactly like your textbox did.

Answer (score 4):

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m=>m.Time new{@id='hdnTime'})
```

Set this in client side from dropdown before you submit

```
$('#hdnTime').val($('#fromDD option:selected').text())
```

Comment: sorry, that was not intentional i just found that your are right

Answer (score 0):

you can pass it as a parameter in your action method

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult ActionName(string FromDD){

}
```

your form have to have action attribute set to ActionName:

```
<form action="ActionName">
...
@Html.DropDownList("FromDD",new SelectList (new[] {"first","second","third"}))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use

> @Html.DropDownListFor(u => u.Time,new SelectList (new[] {"first","second","third"}))